# Understanding a sentence from a dialog

Tags: sentence-meaning

From [examenglish.com](http://www.examenglish.com/CAE/scripts/cae_listening1_script0.htm):

> Man:   The world cup starts in three weeks! It’s going to be great!
>
> Woman:   Oh yeah, great.
>
> Man:   Aren’t you into the world cup then?
>
> Woman:   Oh, I don’t mind it, I suppose. When I was younger I used to
>   quite like watching all the fit met running around!

1. I didn't really get what she meant by ***I don't mind it***. **Don't mind sb** means that you can carry on with what you're doing not paying attention to them. But in the context of this dialog it doesn't quite make sense.
2. ***all the fit met running around***
   Not sure, but fit met running around mean sport events near the place where she used to live.

Is it correct?

Comment: **fit met**  is almost certainly a typo.  It should probably be "fit **men**".

Comment: " I don't mind it" - means that she doesn't dislike it, but not really into it that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for one *fit met* is a typo, it should be **fit men**.

In this context *don't mind* is different.
And what she means by '**I don't mind it** is that she doesn't dislike it, but she doesn't really care about it.

Answer (score 3):

In this sense, "I don't mind it" is contrasted with her "being into the World Cup".  To 'be into something' in this sense is to be very engaged or enthusiastic about it.

Her lack of enthusiasm in her reply could have signaled that she either doesn't care about the World Cup, or is apprehensive about it.  By saying "she doesn't mind it", she is clarifying that she is neither apprehensive nor particularly looking forward to it.

EDIT - also, as others have mentioned, "fit met" is a typo and should read "fit men".  It might be helpful to know that while understood easily in both, the sense of "fit" here is more used in British English than in American English.